# Error when doing Unit Test with CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to do a unit test using test recorder with Codename One. Everything goes smoothly, but when I run the test I keep receiving an error:

> [java] Failed to open VKB: Cannot run program
>   "C:\WINDOWS/system32/osk.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested
>   operation requires elevation
>
> [java] Failed to open VKB: Cannot run program "C:\WINDOWS/system32/osk.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested
>   operation requires elevation
>
> [java] No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\User\Desktop\SQLiteStudio\KudosDB.db

SQLite library is there. When I try to write my own script and run it, it works, but not when using the test recorder. Please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it more readable

Comment: Make sure your libraries are up to date. How are you initializing the tests and creating them? Which test framework are you using? How are you running it?